# What events are described in these entries on the reputation page?

Tags: support, reputation

My reputation page on Programmers reports the following entries.

[image: screenshots]

They are referring to questions that have been deleted, and for which the reputation I gained for accepting an answer has been removed. The links take to the two [accepted](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/260/should-programming-be-taught-instead-of-advanced-mathematics-in-school/261#261) [answers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/266/will-net-applications-replace-applications-using-native-code/291#291), which are visible only to 10k users.

In the same page, I notice the following events.

[image: screenshot]

I would have though these entries were reporting reputation I gained for accepting answers in now deleted questions, but they are described differently from the previous ones. I take the reputation lose is caused by something that has been removed, but I cannot understand what the exact reason is. I lose 2 points when I get down-voted, but when the post is deleted, I should eventually get back those two points.

What events are described in those entries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They mean different things:

- **unaccept**: the accept vote was retracted
- **removed**: the post itself was deleted

"removed" is -2 here because 2 rep was all that post had on it relating to you...it might be 12 or 22 in other cases for example.

Comment: Does that include also the reputation I gain for suggesting an edit that is approved? That is the only +2 I can think of, and that I could gain from a post for a question that is not mine.

Comment: @kiamlaluno You could also get +2 for accepting an answer (although I'm sure you'd notice if an answer you'd accepted was deleted), or from upvotes when you are just shy of the rep cap.